# Relabeling one level of a Columns MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Labels     strategy              firm              
buysell           1   2   4   5     1   2   4   5  
2                 1 NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3                 1   1 NaN NaN     1   2 NaN NaN 
4                 3   1 NaN NaN     2   3 NaN NaN
5               NaN NaN   2 NaN     1   6   3 NaN
6                 1  13   1 NaN     1  13   6 NaN
7               NaN  17  18 NaN     1   8  11 NaN
8               NaN   5  16   1   NaN   7  23   2
9               NaN   1  12   5   NaN NaN   6   5
10              NaN   1 NaN   2   NaN NaN NaN   1
```

To make things clear, the columns of this DataFrame are a MultiIndex with level 0 being the Labels "strategy, firm, ..." and level 1 being the buysell scores "1, 2, 4, 5". There is one set of buysell scores for each label.

Instead of "1, 2, 4, 5", I'd like level 1 of my columns MultiIndex to be "ss, s, b, sb". Is there any way I can reset the labels of this label while preserving the other level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only changing the level labels without changing the structure of it, it makes sense to use the buildin `set_level` method, instead of generating the index all over again:

```
In [18]:
df.columns.set_levels([df.columns.levels[0], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']])
print df
    strategy              firm            
           a   b   c   d     a   b   c   d
0                                         
2          1 NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3          1   1 NaN NaN     1   2 NaN NaN
4          3   1 NaN NaN     2   3 NaN NaN
5        NaN NaN   2 NaN     1   6   3 NaN
6          1  13   1 NaN     1  13   6 NaN
7        NaN  17  18 NaN     1   8  11 NaN
8        NaN   5  16   1   NaN   7  23   2
9        NaN   1  12   5   NaN NaN   6   5
10       NaN   1 NaN   2   NaN NaN NaN   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just managed to figure something out myself:

```
l = ['ss', 's', 'b', 'sb']
level0 = df.columns.levels[0][df.columns.labels[0]]
mult = len(df.columns) / len(l)
new_multi = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([level0, l*mult])
df.columns = new_multi
```

And also the general case, assuming the level that needs renaming is the highest one (which appears to be always true in my particular case):

```
new_levels = []
for i in range(len(df.columns.levels) - 1):
    new_levels.append(df.columns.levels[i][df.columns.labels[i]])
l = ['ss', 's', 'b', 'sb']
mult = len(df.columns) / len(l)
new_levels.append(l * mult)
new_mutli = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(newlevels)
df.columns = new_multi
```

Still, I'm open to suggestions on how to make this more elegant.